# Traveling Outside Italy with an Awaiting Permit Renewal and Valid Student Visa

Tags: italy, permesso-di-soggiorno, residence-permits

If i have a valid student visa and i am awaiting the renewal of my permit but i have the receipt, can i still travel outside of italy? Can i still visit to countries other than  my home country? I know that this question has been answered but it was a long time ago and I'm hoping for a more recent confirmation.